# How to run Anaconda Powershell commands with '--' flags

Tags: python, powershell, anaconda

quick question: How do I run commands like [this](https://github.com/google-research/bert#pre-training-with-bert) ? Where do I run it - powershell?

I downloaded the whole repository and added my paths to the code. If I paste the code into my powershell it gives me errors (not pasting them in here, because they are in german text)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linked example `python` command is for a POSIX-like shell such as `bash`,

- given the use of a line-ending `\` as the line-continuation character.
- and given the use of `/`-based file-system paths without a drive letter.

By contrast, PowerShell uses a line-ending `` ` `` for line continuation - note that it must be the *very last* character.

The following assumes:

- that you'll modify the paths for Window use, if applicable; note that the target Python script file `create_pretraining_data.py` is assumed to be located in the current directory at the time of the call.
- that you've defined variable `$BERT_PATH` with the path to the directory into which you've downloaded "the `BERT-Base` checkpoint" (e.g., `$BERT_PATH = 'C:\path\to\BertBaseDownload'`)
- that calling `python` (by mere file name) runs the target script in the desired Anaconda environment.

```
python create_pretraining_data.py `
  --input_file=./sample_text.txt `
  --output_file=/tmp/tf_examples.tfrecord `
  --vocab_file=$BERT_BASE_DIR/vocab.txt `
  --do_lower_case=True `
  --max_seq_length=128 `
  --max_predictions_per_seq=20 `
  --masked_lm_prob=0.15 `
  --random_seed=12345 `
  --dupe_factor=5
```

Since the line continuations are strictly for *readability*, you can use a single-line form as well (simply omit the line-continuation characters:

```
python create_pretraining_data.py --input_file=./sample_text.txt --output_file=/tmp/tf_examples.tfrecord --vocab_file=$BERT_BASE_DIR/vocab.txt --do_lower_case=True --max_seq_length=128 --max_predictions_per_seq=20 --masked_lm_prob=0.15 --random_seed=12345 --dupe_factor=5
```

You can call the above commands either directly from the interactive PowerShell prompt or from a script file (`*.ps1`).

Comment: @Adrian_G, I don't have BERT, and no Anaconda environment, but as a general tip you need to make sure that all input and output file paths are correct. If you still have trouble, please ask a _new_ question (this question has a clear focus and matching focused answer that solves the _fundamental_ problem); you can use Google Translate to translate German error messages, if needed.